# fourier transform in matlab

Tags: matlab

getting an error while trying to do fourier transform.
my code:

```
    clc;
clear all;
close all;
syms A1 B1 C1 D1 w;

%% define
t = -4:1/100:4;
wm=3*pi;
z=t-(pi/wm);
a=1./(pi*z);
b=sinc(2*wm*z);
c=sinc(wm*z);
A1=fourier(a,z,w);
B1=fourier(b,z,w);
C1=fourier(c,z,w);
D1=fourier(a,z,w);
```

and the error is:

```
Undefined function 'fourier' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Error in h2 (line 13)
A1=fourier(a,z);
```

When I check for "which fourier" to see if I have it, MATLAB is able to give the correct location of the fourier.m on my system. Then why is this occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because Matlab doesn't find the function `fourier`. Be sure that a file named fourier.m resides in your current working directory. Also check if this function is able to work with two parameters. Alternatively you can use `addpath` to add the directory where this file lies.

Maybe you want to use the fast fourier transform from matlab `fft`.

Comment: fourier is a matlab function. also, tried fft, doesn't work as well

Comment: fourier is symbolic toolbox. have you installed this one? check with `ver`.